# Ansible aws_s3 module get file location

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

I have a playbook to download a file from s3 bucket to a target host. I am using the aws_s3 module in ansible. The block looks something like this:-

```
  - name: Get backup file from s3
      aws_s3:
        bucket: "{{ bucket_name }}"
        object: "{{ object_name }}"
        dest: /usr/local/
        mode: get
```

My question is whether this will get the file to the ansible host or to the target host. Should there be any other specification I should be giving to address this difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you delegate this action to another host, it will download the object to the managed nodes (aka. target hosts).